# Error primefaces 5.3 jar

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estoy usando `primefaces` la versión 5.3 y cuando inicio mi proyecto me sale error. Adjunto el código de mi web.xml y el error:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
      <display-name>RecordandoJSF</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
      <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
      </session-config>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.PRIVATE_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
        <param-value>6LfwZwoAAAAAAEhRyntKF1PBzysAJLzqp2v-GMRR</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.PUBLIC_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
        <param-value>6LfwZwoAAAAAAI-oUHpdvRnkMfu9fXQHxc0P7IBu</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>cupertino</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.PUSH_SERVER_URL</param-name>
        <param-value>http://www.primefaces.org:8080</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
      </listener>
      <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
      </filter>
      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      </filter-mapping>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>org.atmosphere.websocket.maxTextMessageSize</param-name>
          <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
      <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/sessionExpired.jsp</location>
      </error-page>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>




       <servlet>
            <servlet-name>ServletImagen</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.cibertec.edu.gestion.util.ServletImagen</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>ServletImagen</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/imagen/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agrega este jar a ver que pasa javax.faces.jar

Comment: puedes comaprtir tu pom? Posiblemente te falte alguna dependencia como la JSF API

Comment: Cuelga el faces-config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es reinstalar  JSF dentro de una carpeta del proyecto, comprobar y meter el primefaces.jar dentro del web-Inf.

No tiene más instalación primefaces